# Free generic linked list in C - segfault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, free, generic-programming

I am writing a generic linked list in C (following *Kyle Loudon*'s book),
but when it comes to free it, I got a **segfault**.

Data types used for the list definition:

```
typedef struct list_elem_
{
    void                *data;
    struct list_elem_   *next;
} list_elem;

typedef struct link_list_
{
    int         size;
    int         (*match)(const void *key1, const void *key2);
    void            (*destroy)(void *data);
    list_elem       *head;
    list_elem       *tail;
} link_list;
```

Function that is used to destroy caller's data:

```
void destroy_data(void *data)
{
    if(data)
        free(data);

    return;
}
```

Destroy passed by a function pointer:

```
void list_init(link_list *list, void (*destroy)(void *data))
{
    list->size = 0;
    list->destroy = destroy;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;

    return;
}
```

Free the list:

```
void list_destroy(link_list *list)
{
    void* data;

    while(list_size(list) > 0)
        if(list_rem_next(list, NULL, (void**)&data) == 0 && list->destroy != NULL)
            list->destroy(data);

    memset(list,0,sizeof(link_list));

    return;
}
```

The segfault is triggered by the free in the destroy_data.

============== EDIT ====================

Remove a list element

```
int list_rem_next(link_list *list, list_elem *element, void **data)
{
    list_elem *OldElement;

    if(list_size(list) ==0)
        return -1;

    /* Remove the head */
    if(element == NULL)
    {
        *data = list->head->data;
        OldElement = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;

        if(list_size(list) == 1)
            list->tail = NULL;

    /* Remove other than head */
    } else {
        if(element->next == NULL)
            return -1;

        *data = element->data;
        OldElement = element->next;
        element->next = element->next->next;

        if(element->next == NULL)
            list->tail = element;
    }

    free(OldElement);

    list->size--;

    return 0;
}
```

=================== EDIT 2 ==========================

Inside main

```
link_list   myList;
int i;
int *iptr;
char *chrPtr;

list_init(&myList, destroy_data);

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    iptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *iptr = i;
    list_ins_next(&myList, NULL, iptr);
}

chrPtr = malloc(sizeof("uno\0"));
chrPtr = "uno\0";
list_ins_next(&myList,NULL,chrPtr);

chrPtr = malloc(sizeof("stringa numero due\0"));
chrPtr = "stringa numero due\0";
list_ins_next(&myList,NULL,chrPtr);

chrPtr = NULL;
iptr = NULL;

getchar();

list_destroy(&myList);
```

Comment: `void destroy_data(void *data) {  if(data) free(data); return; }` :: Burn the book.

Comment: post the definition of `list_rem_next`

Comment: What is the definition of `list_rem_next`

Comment: @wildplasser - I knew another group of people who used to burn books...they were not so friendly though ;) Btw the destroy_data is a function that I have implemented, nothing to do with the book.

Comment: @mateusz.burger: the code for the function could be just `void destroy_data(void *data) { free(data); }` and it would work exactly as well.  The repeated use of `return;` at the end of `void` functions is aconventional at best.  Given the declaration `void *data;`, the cast `(void **)&data` in `list_destroy()` is plain weird too; what other type could the address of a `void *` be than `void **`?  They're enough to raise questions about the validity of what the book does.

Comment: `if(list_rem_next(list, NULL, (void**)&data) == 0 && list->destroy != NULL)` You dont need to cast to void* (or void**), iff you are not living in Java or C++.

Comment: First guess is that list->data points to a string literal (supplied by the caller)

Comment: It's possible that there is nothing wrong with your free code. Your free code assumes that the list has been correctly constructed, which is fine, if that is indeed true. That's why it is important to post a *complete* example demonstrating the problem - it might not be where you think it is. See http://sscce.org.

Comment: Is the book [Mastering Algorithms in C](https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Algorithms-C-Kyle-Loudon/dp/1565924533) by Kyle Loudon?

Comment: Aaarggggghhhh!  `chrPtr = malloc(sizeof("uno\0"));
chrPtr = "uno\0";` —— (a) Why the explicit `\0` when C adds one after it automatically?  (b) Can you say 'memory leak'?  (c) What happened to `strcpy()`?  You are passing unallocated memory pointers to `free()`; in fact, you're passing pointers to string constants to `free()`.  That's undefined behaviour and can very easily lead to crashes!  That's also why the MCVE ([MCVE]) — aka SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example) mentioned by Greg — is so important.  The problem wasn't in the code you showed at first; it was in the other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code from `main()` you have:

```
chrPtr = malloc(sizeof("uno\0"));
chrPtr = "uno\0";
```

1. Why the explicit `\0` when C adds one after it automatically?
2. Can you say 'memory leak'?  You allocate memory; you immediately overwrite the only pointer to that allocated memory by assigning the address of the string literal to the same pointer.
3. What happened to `strcpy()`?

As a result of this abuse, you are passing unallocated memory pointers to `free()`; in fact, you're passing pointers to string constants to `free()`.  That's undefined behaviour and can very easily lead to crashes!

The problem wasn't in the code you showed at first; it was in the other code. That's also why the MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — aka SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org)) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822608/free-genereic-linked-list-in-c-segfault/39822925#comment66935894_39822608) by [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) — is so important.  There's no way for us to debug code you don't show — and it is unnecessarily hard work establishing that the problem isn't in the code you do show.

You could probably use:

```
chrPtr = strdup("uno"));
list_ins_next(&myList, NULL, chrPtr);

chrPtr = strdup("stringa numero due");
list_ins_next(&myList,NULL,chrPtr);
```

to avoid the trouble.  Failing that, you could use:

```
chrPtr = malloc(sizeof("uno"));
strcpy(chrPtr, "uno");
list_ins_next(&myList, NULL, chrPtr);

chrPtr = malloc(sizeof("stringa numero due"));
strcpy(chrPtr, "stringa numero due");
list_ins_next(&myList,NULL,chrPtr);
```

Neither of these checks that the memory allocation succeeded; that too should be done in production code, and arguably in school assignments.

Note that `sizeof("string literal")` counts the null byte, so the length is correct.  Note equally that `strlen("string literal")` does not count the null byte — be careful!

There could still be other problems in the code; I've not verified that everything is clean.  But this part will be cleaner and more likely to work correctly.

---

The functions `list_size()` and `list_ins_next()` are not shown.  The size can be guessed; the `list_ins_next()` is not so easy.

I also observe that the code inserts 4 integers and then 2 strings into the list.  There's no way to know that's what was inserted after the fact.  The code in `main()` is dreadfully non-general.  The support code can handle it — but heterogeneous lists are tricky; don't try it until you don't run into this sort of problem.  One list of integers; fine.  One list of strings; fine.  One list of integers and strings — dodgy!

Comment: Many thanks Joanathan! That was it! Still so many things to learn... Next time I promise I will post a more readable post with a SSCCE

Comment: Learning is what we ask — not repeating the same … mistakes.